# ExtJS FontAwesome change Glyph Color

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, font-awesome

I just added FontAwesome to my ExtJS application.

I added a Glyph to my tab:

```
items: [
        {
            title: 'Dashboard',
            glyph: 0xf009,
            padding: '5',
```

[image]

I would like to change the Glyph color, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
.x-panel-header .x-panel-header-glyph {
    opacity: 1;
    color: red;
}
```

You can see it in action here: http://extjs.eu/examples/#complex-data-binding

Comment: The link doesnt work well I get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null

Comment: The example is fixed now

Comment: Saki I just see glyph: <code> but don't see any special CSS. By the way congrats for your site many interesting things!

Comment: The color is not set in javascript code but by the css similar to above. Use console to browse the DOM and see what is applied to the glyph. You should see opacity:1 and color:#something. Thanks!

Comment: Saki, can you help me with a question please, its breaking my head. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984919/extjs-grid-selectionchange-is-fired-in-other-controller

Answer (score 2):

I tried the Saki way

> .x-panel-header .x-panel-header-glyph {
>       opacity: 1;
>       color: red; }

but then you don't have the control to change attributes for specific glyph and if I want to set it for individual glyph I will need to work harder.

I use a simple way:

Step 1: add a link to the css file

> link rel="stylesheet"
>   href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"

Step: 2:
 use iconCls

> iconCls: "fa fa-lg fa-futbol-o **glyph**"

here I used the awesome classes "fa fa-lg-fa-futbol-o" but I added "glyph" so it will looks better than without.

Step 3:
  define "glyph" in your css file.

> .glyph {  margin-top: 3px; }

Step 4: 
  define any css you can apply to the glyph like color.

The result:

in css file:

> .glyph {  margin-top: 3px; }
>
> .youname {   color: #15498B; }

in js ( every where you have config iconCls )

> iconCls: "fa fa-lg fa-futbol-o glyph youname"

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late but for anyone else in the future who wants change Glyph icons when using custom fonts with Exts.

I used the reference to the button in my controller passed in during the event. I then got the buttons ID then target the button using the get method and concatenating "-btnIconEl" to the the button ID as any glyph/icon will have that CSS.

```
        'button[action=displayGrids]' : {
            click: function(button) { 
                Ext.get(button.id + '-btnIconEl').setStyle('color', '#ffffff');                   
            }
        }
```