# ExtJS Grid SelectionChange is fired in other controller

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have a main application with a left navigation menu. My Main.js controller handles the `treepanelselect` event where a Tab is added:

```
onTreepanelSelect: function (selModel, record, index, options) {
        var mainPanel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('mainpanel')[0];
        var newTab = mainPanel.items.findBy(
                  function (tab) {
                      return tab.title === record.raw.text;
                  });
        if (!newTab) {

            newTab = mainPanel.add({
                xtype: record.raw.class_name, // this is my View widget name
                closable: true,
                iconCls: "key",
                title: record.raw.text
            });
        }
        mainPanel.setActiveTab(newTab);
    },
```

Two of the Navigation menu items are:

- Employee (`controller.Employee`)
- Catalog  (`controller.Catalog`)

`controller.Catalog` is my controller for managing my catalogs and is 100% separate from `controller.Employee` (2 different modules)

Here is my `controller.Catalog`:

```
refs: [
    {
        ref: 'grid',
        selector: '#gridCatalog'
    }],
    init: function (application) {

        this.control({

            'grid': {
                selectionchange: this.gridSelectionChange
            }
        });
    },
 gridSelectionChange: function (model, records) {        
        console.log("Catalog Row Selected");
    },
```

So the view.Catalogs has a `gridCatalog` and on `selectionchange` I get in my console: **Catalog Row Selected.**

On the other side, here is my `controller.Employee`:

```
 refs: [
        {
            ref: 'grid',
            selector: '#gridEmployee'
        }
    ],
    init: function (application) {
        this.control(
             {
                 'grid': {
                     itemdblclick: this.gridDoubleClick
                 }
             });
    },
gridDoubleClick: function (dv, record, item, index, e) {

       // nothing here for the moment.

    }
```

Ok, here is where the Devil comes to scene.

When I run my application, then I click my navigation item "**Employee**" and my tab is created with the view inside it. Until here we are fine.

But.... when I click one of the rows of my `gridEmployee` guess what?? I get in my console: **Catalog Row Selected.**

So, for some reason the `controller.Catalog` is listening to my `gridEmployee`... I don't have a `selectionchange` event handler in my `controller.Employee`. Those file are even in separate module folders inside my "app" folder.

Any clue on what I'm doing wrong? This is breaking my head :(

Comment: Can you create an example at https://fiddle.sencha.com/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your controllers are listening to events from any grid since they are both using the `grid` component query inside init`. Improve your query so that it's not so generic.

```
    init: function (application) {
        this.control(
             {
                 // Don't listen to any grid, just #gridEmployee
                 '#gridEmployee': {
                     itemdblclick: this.gridDoubleClick
                 }
             });
    },
```

Second file

```
    init: function (application) {

        this.control({
            // Don't listen to any grid, just #gridCatalog
            '#gridCatalog': {
                selectionchange: this.gridSelectionChange
            }
        });
    },
```

You seem to have been under the impression that what you use for the refs affected the component query that is passed into `this.control`, but it doesn't See http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-control

Comment: Muchas gracias Juan, so this is normal? I supposed that my controller.Catalog was not going to be loaded until I requested for it.

Comment: Im a newbie for ExtJS and I thought exactly that, If I load some View then it's controller will only listen to the view controls. So what happen if I have other view with a gridCatalog inside?

Comment: Im a little bit confused, because if you see my refs selectors are different, one points to #gridEmployee and the other to #gridCatalog, so why its messing it up :) Appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, all controllers are loaded upfront before any view is loaded. I'm Brazilian, so the correct thing to say is: "Muito obrigado" (instead of Muchas gracias)

Comment: Muito obrigado... have a good Brazilian friend that just went to work to L.A., also an ExtJS expert like you. I will follow you!! Have a nice day and again appreciate your help. (Im from Mexico)

Comment: @VAAA Regarding your question about having another `#gridCatalog`, yes your event will be triggered by any other components that you have assigned the itemId (or ID, but you should never use IDs). The controller is responsible for making sure the query only applies to elements it cares about and needs to make sure the query is unique (much like applying CSS classes to elements). There's much more to be said about best practices for Ext MVC, but it would take way too long.